# CSS class display problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am having the following code from [**this link**](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/) for making a Lightbox effect. It is working fine in Firefox and Google Chrome but having problem in Internet Explorer 8. In IE, all the images and text of the webpage coming above the `black_overlay` and both black and white overlay are in background. Please help in fixing the problem.

```
.black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#666;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.white_content {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 320px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40%;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #d2d2d2;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
    /*margin-top:100px;*/
}
```

HTML:

```
    <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Login</a>
    <div id="light" class="white_content">
         <p>Hello</p>
         <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
    </div>
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

Comment: We need to see your HTM as well.  Or rather a simplified version that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `</div>` after the line `<p>Hello</p>`. Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvdCb/2/).

Comment: Ohh sorry. There is no `</div>`. I edited my question. I am still having problem in IE.

Comment: But if you copy your jsfiddle in a file with lots of images and text then it won't work in IE.

Comment: Can you add them to my jsfiddle and update it, so we can see the problem?

Comment: It is showing correct in jsfiddle. But not displaying correctly in IE :(

Comment: Yes, calling my jsfiddle in the IE8, I can't see a problem.

Comment: (If you have changed the jsfiddle, you have to press 'update')

Comment: Not sure why jsfiddle looks okay in IE by website looks distorted. This is the updated http://jsfiddle.net/zvdCb/6/ (I dont know how this is working fine)